# Warning:"Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle."

Tags: react-native, warnings

Getting this warning in the console when React Native app gets built initially.
Can anyone help me with the reason why I am getting this?

Following are the specifications

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.62.0

Node: v12.9.1

[image]

Comment: Hi, how do you manage to get it fix?
The problem still appear now.

Answer (score 3):

There are generally two categories of cycle warning: one from our own codebase, and another from node_modules packages such as react-navigation-fluid-transitions. In this case, I think it is react-native paper.

We could hardly do anything about the require cycle in node_modules unless the package authors fix it.

But you still wish to keep the package and ignore the warning:

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native'

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
  'Require cycle:'
])
```

Comment: Even if I use what u have suggested, the warning is not being shown in the app but in the logger

Comment: @Anusha see here [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/794). For now you can disable it using patch-package

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by importing each component separately like this:

```
import Button from 'react-native-paper/src/components/Button';
```

```
import IconButton from 'react-native-paper/src/components/IconButton';
```

do similar wherever you are using sth from `react-native-paper`

Answer (score 1):

in your package.json ensure react-native-paper is `"react-native-paper": "^4.5.0",`
Then

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
npm start --reset-cache
```

your react-native-paper warning will disappear

Answer (score 0):

YellowBox is deprecated, use LogBox:

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs([
    'Require cycle:'
])
```

sadly the "Require cycles are allowed" warning is still shown in the logs

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple Providers wrapping your app, make sure your `Provider` imported from `react-native-paper` is way up above in the Hierarchy (there are exceptions like Redux's Provider).

I had multiple providers and had it between other providers, which I think created cycle imports. Fixed the problem when I moved it above the tree, just below redux's provider().

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Provider as PaperProvider} from 'react-native-paper';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import { store } from './your/reduxStore';
import { someTheme } from './your/apptheme';

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    {/* Make sure react-native-paper provider is high up the tree */}
    <PaperProvider theme={muiTheme}>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <StatusBar translucent />
        {/* Your other App Stuff Here */}
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </PaperProvider>
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score -4):

You can go to each path and remove the cycle.

For example, in `node_modules\react-native-paper\src\components\Checkbox\Checkbox.tsx`, remove the reference of `CheckboxItem`.

However, I don't know what the impact of this is.